# mapbox logo spread out of grid in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox GL JS, embedding a map into Wordpress, via plug-in Page Builder-Custom HTML.

HTML

```
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = '*******';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // stylesheet location
    center: [144.9509223,-37.8253897], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
#map { position:static;   }
```

However, the logo always goes out of the grid. Mapbox and 'i' button actually spread full page width. I reckon there is a mapbox css I need to deeply reach to.

I can't use mapbox plugin, as the map will have javascript for user interaction. Any suggestions, please? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

changed to Google Maps, now works like a charm...